# Sencha Touch: how to Update data Store to list from controller

Tags: ajax, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

am facing problem while updating list from controller. I have store, model and list to show Json data. am able to get data but could not able update the list. and if do the ajax call in my store am able to data with list but listners are not getting called. So i moved the code to controller. 
here is my store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.StoreList', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:['MyApp.model.ModelList'],
    config:{
        model:'MyApp.model.ModelList',
        autoLoad:'true',
        storeId:'id_StoreList'
    }
});
```

model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ModelList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype:'modelList',
    config: {
        fields:['name']
}
});
```

controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires : ['MyApp.view.MyList'],
config : {
    refs : {
        loadbtn:'button[action=loadbtn]',
        dataList: '#id_listitems'


    },
    control : {
        "#dataList": {
            itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
        },
        loadbtn:{
            tap : 'handleloadbtn'
        }

    }

},

handleloadbtn: function(){
    console.log('loadbtn tapped');
    Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'loading...'});
    this.ajaxCall();
},

ajaxCall:function(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        method: 'POST',
        scope: this,
        extraParams: {
            Details: true
        },

        url:'http://localhost:9080/works',
        actionMethods: {
            create : 'POST',
            read   : 'POST', // by default GET
            update : 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
        },
        headers :{
            "Content-Type" :'application/xml',
            'Accept':'application/json'
        },
        reader:
        {
            type:'json'
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log('success');

            // var list = Ext.getCmp('id_listitems')
            //var store = Ext.getStore('id_StoreList');
            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('id_StoreList');
            this.getDataList().setStore(store);
           //Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: getDataList is not defined 
            console.log('test:',test);
            Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
        }
    })
}
```

});

list:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyList',{
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'myList',
    requires:['Ext.dataview.List'],
    config:{
        layout:'fit',
        styleHtmlContent:'true',
        styleHtmlCls:'showListCls',
        items:[
            {
                docked:'top',
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        text:'Load',
                        ui:'Plain',
                        action:'loadbtn',
                        width:'180px',
                        height:'30px',
                        docked:'right',
                        margin : '5 15 5 0'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype:'list',
                id: 'id_listitems',
                action:'list_Item_Action',
                store:'StoreList',
                itemTpl:['{name}'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Can any one please help me out in resolving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.getDataList()` like so:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    extraParams: {
        Details: true
    },

    url:'http://localhost:9080/works',
    actionMethods: {
        create : 'POST',
        read   : 'POST', // by default GET
        update : 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    headers :{
        "Content-Type" :'application/xml',
        'Accept':'application/json'
    },
    reader:
    {
        type:'json'
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log('success');

        // var list = Ext.getCmp('id_listitems')
        //var store = Ext.getStore('id_StoreList');
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('id_StoreList');
        this.getDataList().setStore(store);
       //Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: getDataList is not defined 
        console.log('test:',test);
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
    },
    scope: this
});
```

You also need to add `scope: this` to your request config object so that `this` in the `success` method is not the request but your controller.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this. 
your store would look like

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.StoreList', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:['MyApp.model.ModelList'],
    config:{
        model:'MyApp.model.ModelList',
        autoLoad:'true',
         clearOnPageLoad: false,       
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            url: 'http://localhost:9080/works',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: "Items" //It depends on your json data structure

            },
            callbackKey: 'callback'
        }
    }
});
```

In the Controller "handleloadbtn" function , you can just call

```
Ext.getStore("StoreList").load(); //despite of the config "autoLoad:true"
```